# Issues with legend mark colour not the same as the boxplot

Tags: pgfplots, boxplot

I am not able to get the legend colour to be the same as the colour of the lines of boxplot.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
        ushift/.style={
        yshift=0.5cm/1.5},
%        
        dshift/.style={
        yshift=-0.5cm/1.5},
%
    dshift scale/.initial=3em,
    ushift scale/.initial=3em,
%
    /pgfplots/custom legend/.style={
    legend image code/.code={
    \draw [only marks,draw=white,mark=*]
    plot coordinates {(0.3cm,0cm)};},},    
    }
\begin{groupplot}[%
  custom legend,
  legend style={
  legend columns=1,
  column sep=0.5em,
  draw=none,}
  ]
\nextgroupplot[boxplot/draw direction=x,
xmode=log,
ytick={1,2,3},
yticklabels={Grp1, Grp2, Grp3},
xlabel={Counts},
]
%
\addplot+ [% (Primary):
boxplot prepared={
lower whisker= 430000, lower quartile= 220250000,
median= 2000000000,
upper quartile= 10000000000, upper whisker= 1000000000000,
box extend=0.25},
blue, solid, thick, forget plot, dshift] coordinates {};
\addlegendentry{Primary}
%
\addplot+ [% (Secondary):
boxplot prepared={
lower whisker= 430000, lower quartile= 100000000,
median= 2000000000,
upper quartile= 5000000000, upper whisker= 800000000000,
box extend=0.25},
black, solid, thick, ushift] coordinates {};
\addlegendentry{Secondary}
%%
\addplot+ [% (Primary):
boxplot prepared={
lower whisker= 213000, lower quartile= 375000000,
median= 3000000000,
upper quartile= 10000000000, upper whisker= 1000000000000,
box extend=0.25},
blue, solid, thick, forget plot, dshift] coordinates {};
%
\addplot+ [% (Secondary):
boxplot prepared={
lower whisker= 250000, lower quartile= 227000000,
median= 2500000000,
upper quartile= 10750000000, upper whisker= 450000000000,
box extend=0.25},
black, solid, thick, ushift] coordinates {};
%%
\addplot+ [% (Primary):
boxplot prepared={
lower whisker= 75000000, lower quartile= 76100000,
median= 76100000,
upper quartile= 100000000, upper whisker= 500000000,
box extend=0.25},
blue, solid, thick, forget plot, dshift] coordinates {};
%
\addplot+ [% (Secondary):
boxplot prepared={
lower whisker= 1000000000, lower quartile= 1000000000,
median= 1000000000,
upper quartile= 1000000000, upper whisker= 1000000000,
box extend=0.25},
black, solid, thick, ushift] coordinates {};
%
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the corresponding output:

[image: Test]

The line colour of the boxplot for "Secondary" is **black**, but the corresponding colour in the legend is **red**.

Also, the mark position seems to be higher than the line of the legend text.

Answer (score 0):

### Updated plot

[image: Three pairs of boxplots on a logarithmic scale. Each pair has a blue boxplot, for primary, and a black boxplot, for secondary. There is a legend on the top right of the graph indicating the colors corresponding to primary and secondary plots.]

### Changes from your code

- Group plots are for multiple axes aligned together, not just multiple plots. So, we can change `groupplot` to a normal `axis` environment.
- All the boxplots in the official documentation have `\addplot+` for some reason, and I'm not really sure why. However, the plus sign tells PGFPlots to apply both the default style options, *and* the style options you specify such as `blue, solid, thick`. Because the default plot color for the first plot is dark blue, and the default plot color for the second color is dark red, this is why your legend shows both these colors. By deleting the plus signs, we tell PGFPlots to only use your styles, and ignore the defaults.
- In your original boxplots, the `forget plot` option tells PGFPlots that it should overlook a plot when generating the legend. Removing this option ensures that PGFPlots includes these in the legend.
- The upwards shift and downwards shift styles you define in `\pgfplotsset` apply to *everything* associated with those plots, including the legend. This is why the dot marks in the legend appear shifted upwards: both of them are associated with `ushift` plots (the `dshift` plots are skipped due to `forget plot`). Instead, we can use `draw position = ...` to move the pairs of boxplots closer together.

### Code

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
  /pgfplots/custom legend/.style={
    legend image code/.code={
      \draw [only marks,draw=white,mark=*]
      plot coordinates {(0.3cm,0cm)};
    },
  },    
}
\begin{axis}[%
  custom legend,
  legend style={
    legend columns=1,
    column sep=0.5em,
    draw=none,
  },
  ytick={1,2,3},
  yticklabels={Grp1, Grp2, Grp3},
  xmode=log,
  xlabel={Counts},
  boxplot/draw direction=x,
]
\addplot [% (Primary):
boxplot prepared={
  draw position  = 0.82,
  lower whisker  = 430000,
  lower quartile = 220250000,
  median         = 2000000000,
  upper quartile = 10000000000,
  upper whisker  = 1000000000000,
  box extend = 0.25},
blue, solid, thick] coordinates {};
%
\addplot [% (Secondary):
boxplot prepared={
  draw position  = 1.18,
  lower whisker  = 430000,
  lower quartile = 100000000,
  median         = 2000000000,
  upper quartile = 5000000000,
  upper whisker  = 800000000000,
  box extend = 0.25},
black, solid, thick] coordinates {};
%
% --------------------------------------------
%
\addplot [% (Primary):
boxplot prepared={
  draw position  = 1.82,
  lower whisker  = 213000,
  lower quartile = 375000000,
  median         = 3000000000,
  upper quartile = 10000000000,
  upper whisker  = 1000000000000,
  box extend = 0.25},
blue, solid, thick] coordinates {};
%
\addplot [% (Secondary):
boxplot prepared={
  draw position  = 2.18,
  lower whisker  = 250000,
  lower quartile = 227000000,
  median         = 2500000000,
  upper quartile = 10750000000,
  upper whisker  = 450000000000,
  box extend = 0.25},
black, solid, thick] coordinates {};
%
% --------------------------------------------
%
\addplot [% (Primary):
boxplot prepared={
  draw position  = 2.82,
  lower whisker  = 75000000,
  lower quartile = 76100000,
  median         = 76100000,
  upper quartile = 100000000,
  upper whisker  = 500000000,
  box extend = 0.25},
blue, solid, thick] coordinates {};
%
\addplot [% (Secondary):
boxplot prepared={
  draw position  = 3.18,
  lower whisker  = 1000000000,
  lower quartile = 1000000000,
  median         = 1000000000,
  upper quartile = 1000000000,
  upper whisker  = 1000000000,
  box extend=0.25},
black, solid, thick] coordinates {};
%
\addlegendentry{Primary}
\addlegendentry{Secondary}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```